# UINavigationController pop/push UITableViewController only works with animated:NO

Tags: objective-c

My app uses an UINavigationController to show different UITableViewControllers. But with a very strange behavior: pushing an UITableViewController to the navigation controller only works if the animation in `pushViewController:animated:` is set to **NO**.

```
[navController pushViewController:tableController animated:NO]
```

Setting animated to **YES** just freezes the app before showing the tableController view. There is no exception or error at this point. Finally the app crashes after some minutes throwing `EXC_??? (11) (code=0, subcode=0x0)`. But what does this mean?

*Some more information:*

All controllers and views are loaded programmatically. First:

```
UITableViewController *tableController1 = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableController1]
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
```

After clicking a button tableController2 is set using:

```
UITableViewController *tableController2 = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
[navController pushViewController:tableController2 animated:NO];
// -> NO works, YES freezes
```

To analyse tableController2, I also created an own tableViewController. The result is: after clicking the button to load the second table view controller, all methods up to `viewWillAppear` are called. `viewDidAppear` is not called and the view is not shown.

Does anybody have an idea how to find the a solution to solve this problem? Or any ideas, what might be missing in my code? Commenting out a bunch of code and debugging for many hours didn't help yet...

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments, it's better to replace `[self.view addSubview:navController.view];`. So I changed my code and moved the navigation controller init to *appDelegate*. But without success, still the same behavior.

```
UITableViewController *tableController1 = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableController1];
NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, ..., nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

`tabBarController` is just the rootViewController of the app. This should not influence the navigation controller and its controllers.

Comment: I think you are corrupting memory. Use instruments and check memory and leaks.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding navController's view as a subview of self.view. The only way to do that correctly is to also add navController as a child view controller of self, and use the custom container controller api.

Comment: @rdelmar I fixed my code and replaced the `[self.view addSubView:]` (see edit of my question). But I still get the same behavior.

Comment: @shahid-rasheed I already used instruments, and yes there seems to be a leak. But I could not find a reason for that.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted. Are you using ARC? Do you have anything in a storyboard or xib files? It would be good to edit this question -- take out code you're no longer using, and show the whole applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: @rdelmar I'm using ARC, no storyboard and no XIB files. I started to reduce the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and I was ready to put it to my question. And miraculously a final test worked without any problems! What caused the error? I used the following line to set the appearance of UITableView: `[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundView:bgView];` This line freezes the whole app with the configuration described above. Commenting out the line was enough. I **never** would have come to this line of code. So thx for pointing me to applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with initialising your navigation controller.

Try replacing:

```
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
```

with following:

```
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

This of course should be done in your *AppDelegate*.

EDIT:
I'm not sure what is wrong with your project. I created a new project with the same navigation logic as yours.

Here is the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UITableViewController *tvc = [[PSTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc];
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tbc.viewControllers = @[navCtrl, vc];
    self.window.rootViewController = tbc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And here is the table view controllers `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. I just push another table view controller and it works as it should.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewController *detailViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I have uploaded the sample project [here](http://pastelink.me/dl/7b88c2). You can download it and compare with yours. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed my code and replaced `[self.view addSubview:navController.view];` (see edit). But without success, still the same behavior.

Comment: Thx for the test app. I used your app and compared it to my lines of code, but without any success. Most of the lines are also within my applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. After finally reducing all of my code in this method I came across the following line that caused the error: `[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundView:bgView];`.